# What plants have random drops as of version 2.031 in cookie clicker?

Tags: cookie-clicker

I don't know what plants to farm for the drops, i already got the wheat thins from baker's wheat, but what are the others and what do they drop? also E cuz achievement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the wiki](https://cookieclicker.fandom.com/wiki/Garden#Upgrades), there are 7 upgrades that can drop from harvesting mature plants.  They are:

- Elderwort: 1% chance of Elderwort biscuits - +2% cookie production and grandma production
- Bakeberry: 1.5% chance of Bakeberry cookies - +2% cookie production
- Duketater: 0.5% chance of Duketater cookies - +10% cookie production
- Green rot: 0.5% chance of Green yeast digestives - +1% golden cookie gains, effect duration, and frequency; also +3% random drops
- Baker's wheat: 0.1% chance of Wheat slims - +1% cookie production
- Drowsyfern: 1% chance of Fern tea - +3% cps while the game is closed
- Ichorpuff: 0.5% chance of Ichor syrup - +7% cps while the game is closed, sugar lumps mature 7 minutes sooner

Of these, the most important to get first is probably Green yeast digestives because it increases the chance of all other drops by 3%.  You can also use the Mind Over Matter aura to increase the chances of obtaining these random drops by 25% (multiplicatively, not additively).

Comment: im not that far into game, only about 400 prestige level, i was just wondering because i was farming meddleweed for drops but then on the wiki, it said there was only 7 drops

Comment: Thanks m8, much appreciated, i have so many questions cuz i just found this site on a school chromebook and it somehow wasn't blocked, so it seemed like the perfect site to ask questions. i dont have any of those particular plants unlocked but i can actually get them, i have the right plants to breed, but my luck is absolute garbage. so thank you for responding.

Comment: @Parkerdaboss216 if this answers your question, please upvote and mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: idk how to close it so...

Comment: imma just upvote and check it